# amCharts with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm still strugling making work other libs with AngularJS because of it's differtent logic from other libs.
I need to visualize data with amCharts Stock, but there is nothing on the internet about these two wroking together.

How can i make this work with angularjs: http://jsfiddle.net/922JW/

```
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {

    type: "stock",
    "theme": "none",
    pathToImages: "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",

    categoryAxesSettings: {
        minPeriod: "mm"
    },

    dataSets: [{
        color: "#b0de09",
        fieldMappings: [{
            fromField: "value",
            toField: "value"
        }, {
            fromField: "volume",
            toField: "volume"
        }],

        dataProvider: chartData,
        categoryField: "date"
    }],


    panels: [{
            showCategoryAxis: false,
            title: "Value",
            percentHeight: 70,

            stockGraphs: [{
                id: "g1",
                valueField: "value",
                type: "smoothedLine",
                lineThickness: 2,
                bullet: "round"
            }],


            stockLegend: {
                valueTextRegular: " ",
                markerType: "none"
            }
        },

        {
            title: "Volume",
            percentHeight: 30,
            stockGraphs: [{
                valueField: "volume",
                type: "column",
                cornerRadiusTop: 2,
                fillAlphas: 1
            }],

            stockLegend: {
                valueTextRegular: " ",
                markerType: "none"
            }
        }
    ],

    chartScrollbarSettings: {
        graph: "g1",
        usePeriod: "10mm",
        position: "top"
    },

    chartCursorSettings: {
        valueBalloonsEnabled: true
    },

    periodSelector: {
        position: "top",
        dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN",
        inputFieldWidth: 150,
        periods: [{
            period: "hh",
            count: 1,
            label: "1 hour",
            selected: true

        }, {
            period: "hh",
            count: 2,
            label: "2 hours"
        }, {
            period: "hh",
            count: 5,
            label: "5 hour"
        }, {
            period: "hh",
            count: 12,
            label: "12 hours"
        }, {
            period: "MAX",
            label: "MAX"
        }]
    },

    panelsSettings: {
        usePrefixes: true
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would create some basic directive (isolate scope) that receives chart settings and use as template:

```
 <div id="container"></div>
```

In addition we can write several watchers to listen on user actions.

Here is working example How to use it:

*(Its not based on your settings but you can use the same flow)*

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5pov9Ln/)**</kbd>

**Directive**

```
myapp.directive('myElem',
   function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace:true,
            scope: {
            config: '='  
           },
           template: '<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var chart = false;

                var initChart = function() {
                  if (chart) chart.destroy();
                  var config = scope.config || {};
                  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(config);


                  if(config.loading) {
                    chart.showLoading();
                  }

                };
                initChart();

        scope.$watch('config.loading', function (loading) {
          if(loading) {
            chart.showLoading();
          } else {
            chart.hideLoading();
          }
        });

       scope.$watch('config.series[0].type', function (type) {        
         chart.series[0].update({type: type});       
        });

        scope.$watch('config.series[0].dataLabels.enabled', function (enableDataLabels) {          
         chart.series[0].update({dataLabels: {enabled: enableDataLabels}});       
        });                
         }//end watch

       }
   }) ;
```

The usage:

```
 <my-elem config="chartConfig"> </my-elem>
```

**[EDIT]**

Demo 2 <kbd>[FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YnpS/145/)</kbd>

*HTML*

```
<div>     
    <my-elem ></my-elem>    
</div>
```

*JS*

```
    var myapp = angular.module('myModule', []);

myapp.directive('myElem',
   function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace:true,

           template: '<div id="chartdiv" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var chart = false;

                var initChart = function() {
                  if (chart) chart.destroy();
                  var config = scope.config || {};
                   chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
                "type": "serial",
                "theme": "none",
                "marginLeft": 20,
                "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
                "dataProvider": [{
                    "year": "1950",
                    "value": -0.307
                }, {
                    "year": "1951",
                    "value": -0.168
                }, {
                    "year": "1952",
                    "value": -0.073
                }, {
                    "year": "1953",
                    "value": -0.027
                }, {
                    "year": "1954",
                    "value": -0.251
                }, {
                    "year": "1955",
                    "value": -0.281
                }, {
                    "year": "1956",
                    "value": -0.348
                }, {
                    "year": "1957",
                    "value": -0.074
                }, {
                    "year": "1958",
                    "value": -0.011
                }, {
                    "year": "1959",
                    "value": -0.074
                }, {
                    "year": "1960",
                    "value": -0.124
                }, {
                    "year": "1961",
                    "value": -0.024
                }, {
                    "year": "1962",
                    "value": -0.022
                }, {
                    "year": "1963",
                    "value": 0
                }, {
                    "year": "1964",
                    "value": -0.296
                }, {
                    "year": "1965",
                    "value": -0.217
                }, {
                    "year": "1966",
                    "value": -0.147
                }, {
                    "year": "1967",
                    "value": -0.15
                }, {
                    "year": "1968",
                    "value": -0.16
                }, {
                    "year": "1969",
                    "value": -0.011
                }, {
                    "year": "1970",
                    "value": -0.068
                }, {
                    "year": "1971",
                    "value": -0.19
                }, {
                    "year": "1972",
                    "value": -0.056
                }, {
                    "year": "1973",
                    "value": 0.077
                }, {
                    "year": "1974",
                    "value": -0.213
                }, {
                    "year": "1975",
                    "value": -0.17
                }, {
                    "year": "1976",
                    "value": -0.254
                }, {
                    "year": "1977",
                    "value": 0.019
                }, {
                    "year": "1978",
                    "value": -0.063
                }, {
                    "year": "1979",
                    "value": 0.05
                }, {
                    "year": "1980",
                    "value": 0.077
                }, {
                    "year": "1981",
                    "value": 0.12
                }, {
                    "year": "1982",
                    "value": 0.011
                }, {
                    "year": "1983",
                    "value": 0.177
                }, {
                    "year": "1984",
                    "value": -0.021
                }, {
                    "year": "1985",
                    "value": -0.037
                }, {
                    "year": "1986",
                    "value": 0.03
                }, {
                    "year": "1987",
                    "value": 0.179
                }, {
                    "year": "1988",
                    "value": 0.18
                }, {
                    "year": "1989",
                    "value": 0.104
                }, {
                    "year": "1990",
                    "value": 0.255
                }, {
                    "year": "1991",
                    "value": 0.21
                }, {
                    "year": "1992",
                    "value": 0.065
                }, {
                    "year": "1993",
                    "value": 0.11
                }, {
                    "year": "1994",
                    "value": 0.172
                }, {
                    "year": "1995",
                    "value": 0.269
                }, {
                    "year": "1996",
                    "value": 0.141
                }, {
                    "year": "1997",
                    "value": 0.353
                }, {
                    "year": "1998",
                    "value": 0.548
                }, {
                    "year": "1999",
                    "value": 0.298
                }, {
                    "year": "2000",
                    "value": 0.267
                }, {
                    "year": "2001",
                    "value": 0.411
                }, {
                    "year": "2002",
                    "value": 0.462
                }, {
                    "year": "2003",
                    "value": 0.47
                }, {
                    "year": "2004",
                    "value": 0.445
                }, {
                    "year": "2005",
                    "value": 0.47
                }],
                "valueAxes": [{
                    "axisAlpha": 0,
                    "inside": true,
                    "position": "left",
                    "ignoreAxisWidth": true
                }],
                "graphs": [{
                    "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
                    "bullet": "round",
                    "bulletSize": 6,
                    "lineColor": "#d1655d",
                    "lineThickness": 2,
                    "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
                    "type": "smoothedLine",
                    "valueField": "value"
                }],
                "chartScrollbar": {},
                "chartCursor": {
                    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY",
                    "cursorAlpha": 0,
                    "cursorPosition": "mouse"
                },
                "dataDateFormat": "YYYY",
                "categoryField": "year",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "minPeriod": "YYYY",
                    "parseDates": true,
                    "minorGridAlpha": 0.1,
                    "minorGridEnabled": true
                }
            });


                };
                initChart();

           }         
       }
   });
```

Comment: I tried with one simple chart: http://jsfiddle.net/KjbaM/1/ but can't make it work. It's based on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DwZ4a/

Comment: because it even doesn't load angular (module). This is a reason why you see nothing

Comment: This is my working example (copy/paste) based on your link: http://jsfiddle.net/9YnpS/38/

Comment: Anyways, I suggest you to do not hard-code chard data into directive. Make is as template that you can use the same directive in other projects. Just bring it from controller as shown in 1st example.

Comment: Nono, i'll load data from service/factory. Thanks for pointing that, it will need to someone else maybe.

Comment: I have encountered one little problem with your example, chart will load only the first time after i clear cache in the browser, after that it doesn't start.

Comment: Hello Maxim, the amchart fiddle is not working well. can you please help me.

Comment: Sorry the amchart.js file was removed from server you used in fiddle.  Thanks Its working for me ..

Comment: @Janty you welcome to edit my example with working URL if you want. Thank you

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle with amcharts loaded from cdn.js so that the chart is visible again. http://jsfiddle.net/9YnpS/139/

Comment: The answer does not say this clearly, but the first example fiddle is a highcharts example, while the second fiddle is an amcharts example.

Comment: @MaximShoustin how to change type of charts? for example bar?

Answer (score 1):

Use the module
https://github.com/natanielpaiva/angularAmChart

or

project example
https://github.com/natanielpaiva/angularAmChartSimples

Simple:

<amchart ng-model="objectLiveAmchart"> </amchart>

In Javascript:

$scope.objectLiveAmchart = { type:serial, ... }

Answer (score 1):

I fount that the solution provided wasn't working for me.

In particular, the chart was not showing if the id in the template wasn't hardcoded.

It seemed like a problem with the `AmCharts.makeChart()` function that was't able to find the `chardiv_id`in the DOM.

I found that putting the `initChart()`function inside a `scope.$watch('element')` (after attaching `element`to the scope in the linking function) was the right solution for me.

I think this is because after the `element` is created (so after the watch is called) is present and **visible** in the DOM, so the AmChart function can see it and render the chart correctly.

Hope this helped someone!