# I having issues with drawing multiple Amcharts using Angularjs with a single directive

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

[amCharts with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009890/amcharts-with-angularjs) provides solution for hard-coded chart names.

My question is how can I parameterize the value of chartDiv? I want to pass in value od chartDiv as a parameter both in template and the makeChart call to create the chart.

Answer (score 1):

I took the code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23010032/449477) and tweaked it a little: I added in `scope.chartId = attrs.chartId`, then I made the template and `AmCharts.makeChart` both depend upon `chartId`.

You can find the code below, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6jsa36ht/2/) is a JSFiddle.

*HTML*

```
<div>       
    <my-elem chart-id="my-custom-id"></my-elem>    
</div>
```

*JS*

```
var myapp = angular.module('myModule', []);

myapp.directive('myElem',
   function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace:true,
           template: '<div id="{{chartId}}" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.chartId = attrs.chartId;

                var chart = false;

                var initChart = function() {
                  if (chart) chart.destroy();
                  var config = scope.config || {};
                   chart = AmCharts.makeChart(scope.chartId, {
                "type": "serial",
                "theme": "none",
                "marginLeft": 20,
                "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
                "dataProvider": [{
                    "year": "1950",
                    "value": -0.307
                }, {
                    "year": "1951",
                    "value": -0.168
                }, {
                    "year": "1952",
                    "value": -0.073
                }, {
                    "year": "1953",
                    "value": -0.027
                }, {
                    "year": "1954",
                    "value": -0.251
                }, {
                    "year": "1955",
                    "value": -0.281
                }, {
                    "year": "1956",
                    "value": -0.348
                }, {
                    "year": "1957",
                    "value": -0.074
                }, {
                    "year": "1958",
                    "value": -0.011
                }, {
                    "year": "1959",
                    "value": -0.074
                }, {
                    "year": "1960",
                    "value": -0.124
                }, {
                    "year": "1961",
                    "value": -0.024
                }, {
                    "year": "1962",
                    "value": -0.022
                }, {
                    "year": "1963",
                    "value": 0
                }, {
                    "year": "1964",
                    "value": -0.296
                }, {
                    "year": "1965",
                    "value": -0.217
                }, {
                    "year": "1966",
                    "value": -0.147
                }, {
                    "year": "1967",
                    "value": -0.15
                }, {
                    "year": "1968",
                    "value": -0.16
                }, {
                    "year": "1969",
                    "value": -0.011
                }, {
                    "year": "1970",
                    "value": -0.068
                }, {
                    "year": "1971",
                    "value": -0.19
                }, {
                    "year": "1972",
                    "value": -0.056
                }, {
                    "year": "1973",
                    "value": 0.077
                }, {
                    "year": "1974",
                    "value": -0.213
                }, {
                    "year": "1975",
                    "value": -0.17
                }, {
                    "year": "1976",
                    "value": -0.254
                }, {
                    "year": "1977",
                    "value": 0.019
                }, {
                    "year": "1978",
                    "value": -0.063
                }, {
                    "year": "1979",
                    "value": 0.05
                }, {
                    "year": "1980",
                    "value": 0.077
                }, {
                    "year": "1981",
                    "value": 0.12
                }, {
                    "year": "1982",
                    "value": 0.011
                }, {
                    "year": "1983",
                    "value": 0.177
                }, {
                    "year": "1984",
                    "value": -0.021
                }, {
                    "year": "1985",
                    "value": -0.037
                }, {
                    "year": "1986",
                    "value": 0.03
                }, {
                    "year": "1987",
                    "value": 0.179
                }, {
                    "year": "1988",
                    "value": 0.18
                }, {
                    "year": "1989",
                    "value": 0.104
                }, {
                    "year": "1990",
                    "value": 0.255
                }, {
                    "year": "1991",
                    "value": 0.21
                }, {
                    "year": "1992",
                    "value": 0.065
                }, {
                    "year": "1993",
                    "value": 0.11
                }, {
                    "year": "1994",
                    "value": 0.172
                }, {
                    "year": "1995",
                    "value": 0.269
                }, {
                    "year": "1996",
                    "value": 0.141
                }, {
                    "year": "1997",
                    "value": 0.353
                }, {
                    "year": "1998",
                    "value": 0.548
                }, {
                    "year": "1999",
                    "value": 0.298
                }, {
                    "year": "2000",
                    "value": 0.267
                }, {
                    "year": "2001",
                    "value": 0.411
                }, {
                    "year": "2002",
                    "value": 0.462
                }, {
                    "year": "2003",
                    "value": 0.47
                }, {
                    "year": "2004",
                    "value": 0.445
                }, {
                    "year": "2005",
                    "value": 0.47
                }],
                "valueAxes": [{
                    "axisAlpha": 0,
                    "inside": true,
                    "position": "left",
                    "ignoreAxisWidth": true
                }],
                "graphs": [{
                    "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
                    "bullet": "round",
                    "bulletSize": 6,
                    "lineColor": "#d1655d",
                    "lineThickness": 2,
                    "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
                    "type": "smoothedLine",
                    "valueField": "value"
                }],
                "chartScrollbar": {},
                "chartCursor": {
                    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY",
                    "cursorAlpha": 0,
                    "cursorPosition": "mouse"
                },
                "dataDateFormat": "YYYY",
                "categoryField": "year",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "minPeriod": "YYYY",
                    "parseDates": true,
                    "minorGridAlpha": 0.1,
                    "minorGridEnabled": true
                }
            });


                };
                initChart();

         }//end watch           
       }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks Pauan for your answer It does work with a string. However If I pass an angular expression such as   <div>       
    <my-elem chart-id="{{component.id}}"></my-elem>    
</div> The chart is not visible. Although I can see that the chart object gets created. Do you have other suggestions.

Comment: What if it automatically generated an ID for you, would that work?

Comment: ,Yes an automatically generated Id would work. Only criteria is it should be unique across other charts in the page. I am drawing multiple gauge on the same page. My code is  here http://jsfiddle.net/abhi0909/fsn0j03k/

Comment: Well, in that case, does Nataniel's answer work for you? It uses a unique ID, so that you can have multiple charts on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the module
https://github.com/natanielpaiva/angularAmChart

or

project example
https://github.com/natanielpaiva/angularAmChartSimples

Simple:

<amchart ng-model="objectLiveAmchart"> </amchart>

In Javascript:

$scope.objectLiveAmchart = { type:serial, ... }

Comment: Thanks Pauan for your help. How can I pass a JSON object to the data provider instead of hard-coding values in the directive.