# Angularjs, Amcharts do not work with json data object is assigned to data provider instead of actual data

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

How can I pass a `JSON` data object to `dataProvider` in my directive instead of hard-coding actual data to render a graph with `Amcharts` and `Angularjs`?
If `JSON` data is provided instead of a JavaScript object the graph is rendered otherwise the graph is not rendered at all. Although chart title is visible but axis are not created and also the data-points are not displayed in the graph.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('activityChart',
   function ( $timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace:true,
        //scope :true,
        template: '<div id="{{chartId}}"  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; text-align: left;"></div>' ,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            var chart = false;

            var initChart = function() {
                if (chart) chart.destroy();
                $scope.chartId = $attrs.chartId;
                $scope.chartUnit = $attrs.chartUnit;
                $scope.chartData = $attrs.chartData;
                console.log($scope.chartData);
                $timeout(function(){var chart = AmCharts.makeChart($scope.chartId, {
                    "type": "serial",
                    "pathToImages": "/assets/amcharts/images/",
                    "categoryField": "time",
                    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS",
                    "categoryAxis": {
                        "minPeriod": "mm",
                        "parseDates": true
                    },
                    "chartCursor": {
                        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN:SS"
                    },
                    "chartScrollbar": {},
                    "trendLines": [],
                    "graphs": [
                        {
                            "bullet": "round",
                            "bulletSize": 4,
                            "id": $scope.chartId,
                            "title": $scope.chartId,
                            "valueField": "value",
                            "type": "smoothedLine",
                            "lineThickness": 2,
                            "lineColor": "#637bb6"
                        }
                    ],
                    "guides": [],
                    "valueAxes": [
                        {
                            "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                            "title": $scope.chartId + " (" + $scope.chartUnit + ")"

                        }
                    ],
                    "allLabels": [],
                    "balloon": {},
                    "legend": {
                        "useGraphSettings": true
                    },
                    "titles": [
                        {
                            "id": "Title-1",
                            "size": 15,
                            "text": $scope.chartId
                        }
                    ],
                    "dataProvider": $scope.chartData,
                });

                });

            };
            initChart();

        }
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009890/amcharts-with-angularjs

Comment: Is it necessary to have the `chartId` as the elements id?

Comment: Where does the `chartUnit` come from? Binding?

Answer (score 0):

I made a generalized demo for your use case. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tua2vmj/).
The key is to introduce an isolated scope for your directive. This allows you to use the directive multiple times.

If you do it like this:

```
scope: {
    // bi directional binding will pass data array to isolated scope
    data: '=',
    title: '@'
},
```

you can assign the data array from the parent controller:

```
<activity-chart data="data" title="This is the title"></activity-chart>
```

Feel free to ask, if you don't understand how it works.