# Optimal way to use Angular Directives and JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, amcharts

I want an efficient way to factor an Angular Directive that is written to display a chart.

**After reading other answers here,** I found a nice way to create a directive that displays a single chart without any problem.

**How do I reuse the same directive to display different charts? Each chart needs a JSON object that has settings and data in order to render.**

I don't want to pollute my Angular View by typing 100-150 lines of JSON and passing it in via the directive.

Details:-

- Each chart has some common key/value pairs that I can leave in the directive.
- How do I infuse chart specific key & value pairs in each directive?

Eg:- Say I want one chart to have green bars and the other chart to have red lines.

**Angular Directive**

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("analytics")
        .directive("angularDirectiveAmcharts", angularDirectiveAmcharts);

    function angularDirectiveAmcharts() {

        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                chartdata: '=',
                type: '=',
                customstyle: '@',
                chartsettings: '=',
                chartid: '@'
            },
            template: '<div id="{{ chartid }}" style="{{ customstyle }}"></div>'
        };

        return directive;             


        function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
            AmCharts.makeChart(scope.chartid, {
                "type": "serial",
                "categoryField": "date",
                "autoMarginOffset": 10,
                "marginRight": 20,
                "marginTop": 20,

                 //I've deleted lots of keys and values for the sake of brevity


                "dataProvider": scope.chartdata
            });


        }
    }
})();
```

**View**

```
<div class="chartarea" ng-controller="pcController as vm">

    <div angular-directive-amcharts chartid="chartdiv" chartdata="vm.chart_data"></div>

</div>
```

I am particular about maintainability because a lot of changes are going to made after I'm done with my internship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parts of the given code in this answer are based on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23010032/4487044)

You could use a service to provide a standard configuration to all of your chart directives. In this service you can define this standard configuration once and merge it with a specific configuration each time, a directive is created. This way you only have to declare minor changes in your controller.

Nonrequired but possible config binding into directive:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-chart></my-chart>
    <my-chart config="conf"></my-chart>
</div>
```

Specific configuration in controller:

```
myapp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.conf = {
        graphs: [{ type: 'column' }]
    };
});
```

Service for default configuration (using [jQuerys way to deep merge](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) objects):

```
myapp.service('chartService', function () {
    this.defaultConfig = {
        "type": "serial",
        // reduced object for readabilty
    };
    this.getConfig = function (mergeObj) {
        return $.extend(true, {}, this.defaultConfig, mergeObj);
    }
});
```

The data is get through another service, and added to the configuration after the merge:

```
var config = chartService.getConfig(scope.config || {});
config.dataProvider = dataProvider.getData();
chart = AmCharts.makeChart(element[0], config);
```

I've prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysf4bhj1/), so you can take a look into an example.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer.
Yes. I mentioned in my question that I've based my code on other answers that I found on StackOverflow. 

Is there any other way other than this? We at office already thought of  extending it. It becomes cumbersome when we need live data.

Comment: Other way than what exactly? What do you think of extending? I don't understand your questions. Please explain them more precise.